# How is the time spent value at the end of each return message calculated in NebulaGraph Database?

Tags: nebula-graph

As title, in NebulaGraph Database, use `match(v)return(v)limit 5`, the time spent here has two values.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are referring to `(time spent 2687/12519 us)` in any queries from GraphClient like this in NebulaGraph:

```
(root@nebula) [basketballplayer]> match (n) where id(n) == "player100" return n
+----------------------------------------------------+
| n                                                  |
+----------------------------------------------------+
| ("player100" :player{age: 42, name: "Tim Duncan"}) |
+----------------------------------------------------+
Got 1 rows (time spent 2687/12519 us)
```

I am quoting the info from the docs:

> - The first number 2687 shows the time spent by the database itself, that is, the time it takes for the query engine to receive a query from the client, fetch the data from the storage server, and perform a series of calculations.
> - The second number 12519 shows the time spent from the client's perspective, that is, the time it takes for the client from sending a request, receiving a response, and displaying the result on the screen.

ref: https://docs.nebula-graph.io/3.3.0/20.appendix/0.FAQ/#how_is_the_time_spent_value_at_the_end_of_each_return_message_calculated